# Github adding to the project when a pull request or issue is created

Tags: github, graphql, github-actions, github-api, github-graphql

I have a project under my organization and when I create an issue or pull request in my repository, I try to add it to the column I want in the project. The workflow code below works up to the "Set fields" field and directly adds the pull request only to the To do column. In the "Set fields" field, it gives the following error. Can anyone help me with this?

`gh: The single select option Id does not belong to the field`

```
name: Add PR to project

on:
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened] 
    branches:
      - alpha
      - master

env:
  COLUMN_NAME: "In progress"

jobs:
  pr_to_project:
    name : Add PR to project
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Get project data
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.MY_GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          ORGANIZATION: BeycanPress
          PROJECT_NUMBER: 1
        run: |
          gh api graphql -f query='
            query($org: String!, $number: Int!) {
              organization(login: $org){
                projectV2(number: $number) {
                  id
                  fields(first:20) {
                    nodes {
                      ... on ProjectV2Field {
                        id
                        name
                      }
                      ... on ProjectV2SingleSelectField {
                        id
                        name
                        options {
                          id
                          name
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }' -f org=$ORGANIZATION -F number=$PROJECT_NUMBER > project_data.json


          # Set environment variables
          echo "DATE=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo 'PR_ID='${{ github.event.pull_request.id }} >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo 'PR_NUMBER='${{ github.event.pull_request.number }} >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo 'PR_NODE_ID='${{ github.event.pull_request.node_id }} >> $GITHUB_ENV

          echo 'PROJECT_ID='$(jq '.data.organization.projectV2.id' project_data.json) >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo 'DATE_FIELD_ID='$(jq '.data.organization.projectV2.fields.nodes[] | select(.name== "Start date") | .id' project_data.json) >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo 'PR_FIELD_ID='$(jq '.data.organization.projectV2.fields.nodes[] | select(.name== "Linked pull requests") | .id' project_data.json) >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo 'STATUS_FIELD_ID='$(jq '.data.organization.projectV2.fields.nodes[] | select(.name== "Status") | .id' project_data.json) >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo 'TODO_OPTION_ID='$(jq '.data.organization.projectV2.fields.nodes[] | select(.name== "Status") | .options[] | select(.name=="${{ env.COLUMN_NAME }}") |.id' project_data.json) >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: Add PR to project
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.MY_GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        run: |
          item_id="$( gh api graphql -f query='
            mutation($project:ID!, $pr:ID!) {
              addProjectV2ItemById(input: {projectId: $project, contentId: $pr}) {
                item {
                  id
                }
              }
            }' -f project=$PROJECT_ID -f pr=$PR_NODE_ID --jq '.data.addProjectV2ItemById.item.id')"

            echo 'ITEM_ID='$item_id >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: Set fields
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.MY_GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        run: |
          gh api graphql -f query='
            mutation (
              $project: ID!
              $item: ID!
              $status_field: ID!
              $status_value: String!
              $date_field: ID!
              $date_value: Date!
            ) {
              set_status: updateProjectV2ItemFieldValue(input: {
                projectId: $project
                itemId: $item
                fieldId: $status_field
                value: {
                  singleSelectOptionId: $status_value
                  }
              }) {
                projectV2Item {
                  id
                  }
              }
              set_date_posted: updateProjectV2ItemFieldValue(input: {
                projectId: $project
                itemId: $item
                fieldId: $date_field
                value: {
                  date: $date_value
                }
              }) {
                projectV2Item {
                  id
                }
              }
            }' -f project=$PROJECT_ID -f item=$ITEM_ID -f status_field=$STATUS_FIELD_ID -f status_value=$TODO_OPTION_ID -f date_field=$DATE_FIELD_ID -f date_value=$DATE --silent
```

Comment: Did you by chance type `Id` somewhere that expected `id`? The error message seems to point to that but I can't find an uppercase `Id` in your code.